# Exception Debugging using Unity IOC

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm having issues getting good Exception information when using Microsoft.Practices.Unity to load some classes dynamically.

The code is on a remote server and I'm using ELMAh to capture errors.  I see the exceptions but the exception information stops at DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IMyClass_GUID.MyFunction().

I've pushed debug classes to the server so I see the line numbers up to that point but I can't get the line numbers for these dynamically loaded classes.

Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere that allows the real inner exception information to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Unity includes all the chain of the errors in the InnerException, of each one. For example if you have a chain of dependency like this: `Service1` dependes on `Service2` depends on `Service3`

and, if Unity failed to instanciate Service3 due to a resolution error, you'll get a resolution failed exception of Service1 having an InnerException of type resolution failed exception of Service2 having an InnerExcepetion of type resolution failed exception of Service3.

Comment: My issue is with an exception inside Service 2 for example.  I don't get debug information for Service 2 DLL.  I ended up finding my bug by removing Unity for that one class call and I got the error info in the exception.